# Why do we use the "class << self" expression?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby there are several ways to declare a class method.

We have these two forms...

```
class Dog

  def self.species
    puts "I'm a dog."
  end

  def Dog.species_rly?
    puts "Still a dog."
  end

end
```

And this other, longer form...

```
class Dog
  class << self
    def species_srsly?
      puts "OK, fine. I'm a cat."
    end
  end
end
```

Why is the last form used? How is it better than just doing this?

```
class Dog
  def Dog.some_method
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: `Dog.species` is problematic if you change the class name later. Better use `self.species`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class << self` is the least repetitive. `def Dog.meth` repeats "Dog" all over the class, and `def self.meth` repeats "self".

The extra indentation might also be a visual indicator that you're in your singleton-ish class methods and not your regular instantiated methods.

Answer (score 3):

[This wonderful book](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) says that the three syntaxes are identical. Which one to choose is a matter of personal preference. It also says that class name syntax (`def Dog.some_method`) is frowned upon by Ruby community. And I can see why: you're duplicating information without a reason. Should you rename your class, you'll have to update all method definitions as well.

So, you're free to choose between the remaining two syntaxes :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll find that the `class << self` form is only longer when you're dealing with a small number of methods. If you are going to write, say, 15 class methods, suddenly it's a lot clearer and a lot less repetitive.

At the end of the day it's a matter or personal style which you use.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no difference, and it's ultimately a matter of preference. Some like the latter because it brings all the "class" methods into a single block and avoids having to write `self.` in each method definition.

The former makes the fact that each method is a "class" method explicit in each definition.

I don't think I would ever use the `Dog.some_method`, as it makes refactoring more difficult than `self.some_method`.

Answer (score 1):

Technical there is no difference (at least I know none).

I avoid

```
class Dog
  def Dog.species_rly?
    puts "Still a dog."
  end
end
```

If I change the class name, I have to change it in each method definition.
Same, if I copy a method from one to another class (if you do so, think first, if you should define a module and inlcude it).

If I have one or two methods I use:

```
class Dog

  def self.species
    puts "I'm a dog."
  end

end
```

If I have more class methods, then I first think why.
Class methods are often just a hint for bad design - 
perhaps you need another (singleton?) class.

If I decide to define multiple class methods I use:

```
class Dog
  class << self
    def species_srsly?
      puts "OK, fine. I'm a cat."
    end
  end
end
```

Sometimes I separate the class methods in a sourcefile and put the instance methods in another sourcefile.

Answer (score 0):

In the class Dog, self is the 'Dog' class (every class has a 'class' object, sometimes called a meta-class or eigenclass).

In a tricky way, all methods in ruby are instance methods.

```
def self.species
```

is declaring a species method on the 'class class', which makes it (behave like) a class method.

Similarly,

```
d = Dog.new
def d.bark; puts "woof"; end
```

adds a method to the 'd' instance

As to the difference between

```
class << self
  def species
```

and

```
def self.species
```

they functionally accomplish the same thing.  Choosing one format over the other, as mentioned in others, is stylistic.  def self.species is the usual one for declaring 'class' methods.

I mostly would use

```
class << self
  attr_accessor :species
end
```

if I were to want to make an attribute accessor operate on the class level, rather than instance.

Understanding this is important to using hooks like the module included

```
module Sound
  def self.included(host_class)
    def host_class.speak(sound)
      define_method(:bark) do
        sound
      end
    end
  end
end
class Dog
  include Sound
  speak "woof"
end
Dog.new.bark
```

Also, for completeness

```
class Dog
  def self.species
    puts self.to_s
  end
  def Dog.bark
    puts self.to_s
  end
end
class Spaniel < Dog; end
```

The species method is defined on the self of any subclasses, whereas the :bark method is always defined on Dog (unless overwritten)